# Add a noNamespaceSchemaLocation using XmlWriter in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlwriter

I have to build an xml as a confirmation of receipt of a postscript file. I have all the code done but the example shows a nonamespace which I cannot get to appear correctly.

The example looks like this:
`<CapCommsStatus xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="CapCommsStatus_v1.xsd">`

Nearest I have got to is this:
`<CapCommsStatus xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" p2:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="CapCommsStatus_v1.xsd" xmlns:p2="xsi">`

```
        Dim writersettings As New XmlWriterSettings
        Dim writer
        With writersettings
            .Indent = True
            .IndentChars = vbTab
            .NewLineChars = vbCrLf
            .NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace
            .Encoding = New UTF8Encoding(False)
        End With
        writer = XmlWriter.Create(outputName, writersettings)
        writer.WriteStartDocument(True)
        writer.WriteStartElement("CapCommsStatus")
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", vbNull, "CapCommsStatus_v1.xsd")
```

Comment: Why is xsi defined twice in the sample?

Comment: No idea, I had considered just leaving the namespace out altogether but thought I should at least attempt to recreate it but it didn't seem that unusual. I've seen similar attributes in root tags before in xml where the nonamespaceschemalocation is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so not using .Create gave me the output I was looking for:

````
 writer = New XmlTextWriter(outputName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
            writer.WriteStartDocument(True)
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
            writer.WriteStartElement("CapCommsStatus")
            writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
            writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "CapCommsStatus_v1.xsd")```
````

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution that is using LINQ to XML API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

It allows to compose a desired XML in one single statement.

**VB.NET**

```
Sub Main
    Dim xsi As XNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    Dim xelem As XElement = New XElement("CapCommsStatus", _
        New XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi.NamespaceName), _
        New XAttribute(xsi + "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "CapCommsStatus_v1.xsd"))

    Console.WriteLine(xelem)
End Sub
```

**Output**

```
<CapCommsStatus xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="CapCommsStatus_v1.xsd"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest e.g.

```
    Using writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out, writersettings)
        writer.WriteStartDocument(True)
        writer.WriteStartElement("CapCommsStatus")
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "CapCommsStatus_v1.xsd")
    End Using
```